# Cube.js QueryBuilder does not rerender when new timeDimensions provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cube.js

I'm trying to get cube.js client showing data filtered with data provided in `timeDimensions` props.

I'm trying all latest version.

I have tried `QueryBuilder` render props method `updateTimeDimensions` ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-builder-with-cubejs-1esln)). Tried update time dimensions and pass to `query` props ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-builder-with-cubejs-5xfez)).

Here is the passing props version:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [dateRange, updateDateRange] = useState([
    moment("2019-01-01").format(defaultFormat),
    moment('2019-04-01').format(defaultFormat)
  ]);
  const query = {
    timeDimensions: [
      {
        dimension: "LineItems.createdAt",
        granularity: "month",
        dateRange
      }
    ]
  }
  console.log(query)
  console.log(dateRange)
  return (
    <>
      <RangePicker
        defaultValue={[moment("2019-01-01"), moment('2019-04-01').startOf("day")]}
        onChange={([startDate, endDate]) => {
          updateDateRange([
            startDate.format(defaultFormat),
            endDate.format(defaultFormat)
          ]);
        }}
      />
      {dateRange && <QueryBuilder
        query={query}
        cubejsApi={cubejsApi}
        render={({
          resultSet,
          measures,
          availableMeasures,
          updateMeasures
        }) => (
          <Layout.Content style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
            <Select
              mode="multiple"
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              placeholder="Please select"
              onSelect={m =>
                updateMeasures.add(find(propEq("name", m))(availableMeasures))
              }
              onDeselect={m =>
                updateMeasures.remove(
                  find(propEq("name", m))(availableMeasures)
                )
              }
            >
              {availableMeasures.map(measure => (
                <Select.Option key={measure.name} value={measure.name}>
                  {measure.title}
                </Select.Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
            <Divider />
            {measures.length > 0 ? (
              <ChartRenderer resultSet={resultSet} />
            ) : (
              <Empty description="Select a measure and date range to get started" />
            )}
          </Layout.Content>
        )}
      />}

    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Log show `dateRange` when changing date rage as expected. But cube.js component rerendering not triggered when changing date range.

```
Object {timeDimensions: Array[1]}
["2019-01-01", "2019-04-01"]
Object {timeDimensions: Array[1]}
["2019-01-01", "2019-04-30"]
Object {timeDimensions: Array[1]}
["2019-01-01", "2019-05-31"]
```

Answer (score 1):

When `updateDateRange` is called it overwrites whole `query` state of `QueryBuilder` which removes any `measures` set before. When you maintain `query` state outside of `QueryBuilder` you should pass `setQuery` to update your own state when it's changed by `QueryBuilder`: https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-client-react#query-builder-props

Please see updated example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-builder-with-cubejs-4jwj5

```js
const App = () => {
  const [dateRange, updateDateRange] = useState([
    moment("2019-01-01").format(defaultFormat),
    moment("2019-04-01").format(defaultFormat)
  ]);

  const [query, setQuery] = useState({});

  const applyNewQuery = query => {
    let newQuery = query;
    if (newQuery.timeDimensions && newQuery.timeDimensions[0]) {
      newQuery = {
        ...newQuery,
        timeDimensions: [
          {
            ...newQuery.timeDimensions[0],
            dateRange,
            granularity: "month"
          }
        ]
      };
    }
    setQuery(newQuery);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    applyNewQuery(query);
  }, [dateRange]);

  return (
    <>
      <RangePicker
        defaultValue={[
          moment("2019-01-01"),
          moment("2019-04-01").startOf("day")
        ]}
        onChange={([startDate, endDate]) => {
          updateDateRange([
            startDate.format(defaultFormat),
            endDate.format(defaultFormat)
          ]);
        }}
      />
      {dateRange && (
        <QueryBuilder
          query={query}
          setQuery={applyNewQuery}
          cubejsApi={cubejsApi}
          render={({
            resultSet,
            measures,
            availableMeasures,
            updateMeasures
          }) => (
            <Layout.Content style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
              <Select
                mode="multiple"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Please select"
                onSelect={m =>
                  updateMeasures.add(find(propEq("name", m))(availableMeasures))
                }
                onDeselect={m =>
                  updateMeasures.remove(
                    find(propEq("name", m))(availableMeasures)
                  )
                }
              >
                {availableMeasures.map(measure => (
                  <Select.Option key={measure.name} value={measure.name}>
                    {measure.title}
                  </Select.Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
              <Divider />
              {measures.length > 0 ? (
                <ChartRenderer resultSet={resultSet} />
              ) : (
                <Empty description="Select a measure and date range to get started" />
              )}
            </Layout.Content>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```